# How to call ApplicationController methods from ApplicationHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, view-helpers

I want to provide csv links in a view and I placed the csv generating code in `ApplicationHelper`. However I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `send_data' for #<#<Class:0x0000010151c708>:0x0000010151a070>
```

referencing this:

```
send_data content, :type => "text/plain",
  :filename => filename,
  :disposition => 'attachment'
```

If I place the csv code in a controller it works fine. I was hoping to use the helper to avoid having to define routes for every controller I want to provide csv options for (I have a bunch). How can I make `send_data` (and other necessary methods) available to the helper?

Comment: Untested Thought: Check what the class name it is being called on. Does renaming the method to something else help (it could be that send_data is a already-defined method by rails?)

Comment: Yes it is a rails-defined method, but it seems to be accessible only though controllers.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

#### Use `helper_method`.

By default, methods in `ApplicationController` are only accessible inside the Controllers.

Add a method to the `ApplicationController` and expose it as a helper method with `helper_method`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :foo

  def foo
    "bar"
  end

end
```

Now the `foo` method is accessible to both Controllers *and* Views.

Comment: I think that puppy icon made me upvote you. So smart Harish!

Answer (score 10):

If the issue is to make methods in ApplicationHelper available in all controllers, why not add a line

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

to the ApplicationController file?